# subtracting input field width? jquery help subtract syntax?

Tags: jquery, syntax, width

I'm trying to adjust a width of the input field based on some jquery. It seems to not be working for me.

This is my code

```
        var textWidth = $('#textWidth').width();
        var inputWidth = $('input#inputWidth ').width();
        var newInputWidth = inputWdith - textWidth;
        $('input#inputWidth ').width(newInputWidth); //new width of input field
        alert(newInputWidth);
```

Is my syntax wrong? I'm thinking that the minus isn't correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo: `inputWdith`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mu is too short just solved it for me! Thanks, thats exactly what was wrong. Great catch!